# SQL Server Agent - Report Failure but continue When intermediate step fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL Server Agent job that has three steps with the following control flow:

- Step 1 - on success - Go to next Step. on fail - job fails
- Step 2 - on success - Go to next Step. on fail - Go to next Step
- Step 3 - on success - report success, on fail - report fail

However, What I want to happen is, if step 2 fails, run step 3 but report that the job has failed (regardless of whether step 3 is successful or not)

The only way I can think to do this is as per the screenshot below which duplicates the final step but the duplicate step reports failure if it succeeds

[image]

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm wondering if the accepted answer for [Notify Operator if ANY step in job fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858472/notify-operator-if-any-step-in-job-fails) would solve your problem.

Comment: I've used something like the suggestion that Scotts links to in my MailAfterJob procedure (https://karaszi.com/mailafterjob-send-email-after-agent-job-include-ouput-files), and it has worked fine for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is just add one more step "Error" between step #2 and #3 that sends an  email.
Something like this:
[image]